# Animation flashes problems

Tags: java, javafx

When i ran the following codes ,i got to find that before the animation in the setOnfinished() runs, the button object will flash suddenly and i can't figure out why.(Because i can't make a gif to show the result , so maybe you need bother to run on your PC. Thanks in advance!)

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Pane pane=new Pane();
        Button bt=new Button("");
        bt.setPrefSize(40, 40);
        bt.setLayoutX(0);
        bt.setLayoutY(0);

        Line line1=new Line(20,20,20,100);
        PathTransition pt1=new PathTransition();
        pt1.setPath(line1);
        pt1.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));

        Line line2=new Line(20,100,100,100);
        PathTransition pt2=new PathTransition();
        pt2.setPath(line2);
        pt2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));

        SequentialTransition st=new SequentialTransition(bt,pt1,pt2);
        st.play();
        st.setOnFinished(e->{
            bt.setLayoutX(80);
            bt.setLayoutY(80);
            System.out.println("X coordinate"+bt.getLayoutX());
            System.out.println("Y coordinate"+bt.getLayoutY());
            Line line3=new Line(20,20,20,90);
            PathTransition pt3=new PathTransition();
            pt3.setPath(line3);
            pt3.setNode(bt);
            pt3.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
            pt3.play();
            primaryStage.show();

        });

        pane.getChildren().add(bt);
        Scene scene=new Scene(pane,250,250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        System.out.println("X coordinate"+bt.getLayoutX());
        System.out.println("Y coordinate"+bt.getLayoutY());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on animations but setting the coordinates manually seems odd.

Comment: I also doubt that it's setting coordinates that causes the problem, but i don't know why...~_~

Comment: Well I'd assume that the button would have different coordinates due to the animation so when you change them you make the button appear in the wrong place for at least one frame (which would explain that flashing).

Comment: I thought this this was most likely to be the reason. But in fact the start point coordinates should be the coordinates of the central point of a node,so do the end point .And the coordinates of a button are defined as the coordinates of top-left vertex .So i calculated them and set these numbers. I think they are not wrong. This is exactly where i am feeling confused.

Comment: But still thanks for your answer ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Thomas said, you set the wrong coordinates in the onFinish method. You should have picked up at the last position of the button and move from there.

```
    Pane pane=new Pane();
    Button bt=new Button("");
    bt.setPrefSize(40, 40);
    bt.setLayoutX(0);
    bt.setLayoutY(0);

    Line line1=new Line(20,20,20,100);
    PathTransition pt1=new PathTransition();
    pt1.setPath(line1);
    pt1.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));

    Line line2=new Line(20,100,100,100);
    PathTransition pt2=new PathTransition();
    pt2.setPath(line2);
    pt2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));

    SequentialTransition st=new SequentialTransition(bt,pt1,pt2);
    st.play();
    st.setOnFinished(e->{
        System.out.println("X coordinate"+bt.getLayoutX());
        System.out.println("Y coordinate"+bt.getLayoutY());
        Line line3=new Line(100,100,100, 190);
        PathTransition pt3=new PathTransition();
        pt3.setPath(line3);
        pt3.setNode(bt);
        pt3.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        pt3.play();
        primaryStage.show();

    });

    pane.getChildren().add(bt);
    Scene scene=new Scene(pane,250,250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    System.out.println("X coordinate"+bt.getLayoutX());
    System.out.println("Y coordinate"+bt.getLayoutY());
```